# what is wrong with this if-statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

I have absolutely no idea what is wrong with this if statement, when I sent values lon = -3 and lat = 7 it should return false but it doesn't.

```
  if (b < 0 && ((lon > 8 && lon < 0) || (lat > 8 && lat < 0)))
  {

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true ;
  }
```

Comment: what's the value of b?

Comment: The clauses `(lon > 8 && lon < 0)` and `(lat > 8 && lat < 0)` makes no sense... I mean, they're never going to evaluate to `true`... How can `lon` and `lat` be greater than 8 and less than 0 at the same time?

Comment: @AlexandreLucchesi You should have posted an answer, because that's "*what is wrong with this if-statement*"

Comment: @IvanStoev Done. :)

Answer (score 1):

decomposing each value...

```
int lon = -3;
int lat = 7;

  if (b < 0 && // i don't know b value
            ((-3 > 8 && //false
            -3 < 0)     //true
     || (7 > 8 && //false
     7 < 0 //false
     ))) 
  {

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true ;
  }
```

it results in
    int lon = -3;
    int lat = 7;

```
  if (b < 0 && // i don't know b value
            (false || false)) 
  {

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true ;
  }
```

and finally is:

```
  if (false) 
  {

    return false;
  }
  else
  {
    return true ;
  }
```

then it return true!

Answer (score 1):

Though the logic flawed with this `if` statement, maybe there is still something to be learned here. Instead of evaluating the `if` statement and then returning either `true` or `false`, you could clean that up a bit and just do something like:

```
return b < 0 && ((lon > 8 && lon < 0) || (lat > 8 && lat < 0))
```

But back to the logical error, perhaps your understanding of how the inequality operators work. It would make more sense if you did something like `lon > 0 && lon < 8` which would read as *longitude is greater than zero and less than eight*.

Answer (score -1):

If i am reading your statement correct you will never ever get false. To get false lon must me less than zero AND more than 8 ... that is not possible. The same case with lat.

Comment: He'll never get true because of flawed logic.

Comment: whoot...could one explain to me why my correct answer is getting downvoted?

Comment: I've explained it already. You'll ways get false not 'never ever get false'. You're answer is plain wrong. The statement will evaluate to false if one side of the AND evaluates to false.

Comment: @AlexandreLucchesi I respectfully disagree because the answerer's answer is completely wrong. He's saying that both conditions need to be evaluated as false to return false but that's plain wrong